# USRP B210 failed to send packets

Tags: usrp

I am trying to let USRP B210 communicate with USRP N210. I use the reference code in <>/gnuradio/gr-digital/examples/narrowband,*benchmark_tx* and *benchmark_rx*, to implement the communication. When USRP N210 works as a transmitter and B210 works as a receiver, everything is good. However, if I use B210 as the transmitter, I couldn't get anything at the N210 (receiver) side. And there is no obivous change if *uhd_fft* is used to detect the signal. I try the other B210 board and same situation happens. The followings are the commenda I used to run the python file:

```
python benchmark_rx.py -f 2.1G -r 200000 -m gmsk --args="addr=192.168.10.20"
python benchmark_tx.py -f 2.1G -r 200000 -m gmsk --args="type=b200"
```

Comment: that sampling rate is far too low. Also, um...benchmark_tx isn't actually a great tool to demonstrate operation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 'r' here means transmission rate. With higher transmission gain and larger amplitude we can receive information well. Do you have any other ways to let them communicate by using python?

Comment: I know benchmark_rx,tx quite well, and I know the devices quite well, and your r is too low, because it implies a very low sampling rate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your replying. Even I increase the rate, I stll failed to receive the signal. Do you know why?